# Seg fault on binary search tree - big sorting

Tags: c, string, algorithm, sorting, pointers

Trying to do [this Big Sorting problem on Hackerrank](https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/big-sorting/problem). I know there are simpler ways to write the algorithm, but I am trying to brush up on my C knowledge, and as such wanted to challenge myself and write a Binary Search Tree for the problem.

The binary search tree I wrote seems to work for integers, however, the problem has an input type of strings in the form of numbers. So I tried changing it to using character arrays, and `strcmp()` in order to compare the strings of numbers.

Can someone help me figure out what's going on here, and how I might be able to fix the issue?

Seg-Fault:

```
GDB trace:
Reading symbols from solution...done.
[New LWP 11287]
Core was generated by `solution'.
Program terminated with signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#0  strlen () at ../sysdeps/x86_64/strlen.S:106
#1  0x00007f4f76b2e455 in __strcpy_chk (dest=0xfb0020 "", src=0x0, 
    destlen=105) at strcpy_chk.c:28
#2  0x00000000004007e3 in strcpy (__src=0x0, __dest=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu/bits/string3.h:110
#3  create_node (key=0x0) at solution.c:25
#4  0x00000000004006af in main () at solution.c:70
```

Code:

```
#include <math.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <assert.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

#define MAXLEN 105

struct tree_node {
    char key[MAXLEN];
    struct tree_node *left;
    struct tree_node *right;
}; typedef struct tree_node Node;

Node *create_node(char *key) {
    Node *new_node;

    if ((new_node = (Node*)malloc(sizeof(Node))) == NULL) {
        printf("Cannot allocate memory for new node");
        exit(1);
    }

    strcpy(new_node->key, key);

    //new_node->key = key;
    new_node->left = NULL;
    new_node->right = NULL;

    return (new_node);
}

Node *insertNode(Node *node, char *keyInput) {
    if (node == NULL) {
        return (create_node(keyInput));
    } else {
        if (strcmp(keyInput, node->key) <= 0) {
            node->left = insertNode(node->left, keyInput);
        } else {
            node->right = insertNode(node->right, keyInput);
        }
        return (node);
    }
    return 0;
}

void printTree(Node *tree) {
    if (tree != NULL) {
        printTree(tree->left);
        printf("%s\n", tree->key);
        printTree(tree->right);
    }
}

int main() {
    // Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
    int i, n = 0;
    char *input;
    Node *tree = NULL;

    scanf("%d", &n);

    for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        scanf("%s", input);
        tree = insertNode(tree, input);
    }

    printTree(tree);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pass an uninitialized pointer to `scanf()` to read a string. You should instead define `input` as an array:

```
int main(void) {
    // Enter your code here. Read input from STDIN. Print output to STDOUT
    int i, n;
    char input[105];
    Node *tree = NULL;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
            if (scanf("%104s", input) != 1)
                break;
            tree = insertNode(tree, input);
        }
        printTree(tree);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

The problem with this approach is it does not fit the problem space:

- The website says the lines contain numbers encoded in decimal without leading zeroes, but up to 10<sup>6</sup> bytes long.  You cannot parse such input portably and efficiently with `scanf().
- Furthermore, `strcmp()` is inappropriate to compare these entries: you should first compare the lengths and only use `strcmp()` on entries with the same number of digits.

Comment: Got it, that makes sense. And the `%104s` - is that necessary, or just added precaution we are not taking too much memory?

Comment: Hardcoding 104 kind of defeats the purpose of using a MAXLEN define.

Comment: @Dukeling: yes, `scanf()` is so clunky I should do away with the define.

Answer (score 1):

Focus here:

```
char *input;
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("%s", input);
}
```

Where will be the read string going to be stored? `input` is `char` pointer that doesn't point anywhere near valid memory space!

Let's allocate some memory for it by defining it as an array:

```
char input[MAXLEN];
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    scanf("104%s", input);
}
```

Do not forget the space needed by the null-terminator, that's why I used 104 (`MAXLEN` - 1), which is a precaution in order not to take more memory than `input` can store.

Moreover, you could take advantage of what [`scanf()`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/scanf/) returns and do this:

```
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
    if( scanf("%104s", input) != 1 )
        break; // didn't read a one string, break the loop!
    // I got the input, let's insert it to the tree..
}
```

Comment: Got it, yeah that makes sense. A bit rusty, so that's why I'm working on this. Thanks!

Comment: `"104%s"` -> `"%104s"`